# How To Preserve File Names when Programmatically Downloading from Google Drive

Tags: curl, google-drive-api, wget, google-docs, google-docs-api

So, I have a bunch of file IDs for docments on Google Drive. I want to download them all as `docx` and convert them into markdown files *with the same names as what's on Google Drive.* (The same-name thing is what I'm stuck on.)

What gets close is this:

`curl -L -O  'https://googledrive.com/host/<FILEID>&exportFormat=docx'`

or similarly

`curl -L 'https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/<FILEID>/export?format=docx' -o <FILEID>.docx`

The first example sucks because the file just gets named '&exportFormat=docx'. Similarly, the second example isn't any better, naming the file '.docx'.

For *some documents*, I can extract the title using pandoc. However, some documents lack a `title` property. (It's also reasonable that someone would want to do this with a file type that didn't embed a title property, or did but it didn't correspond to the file's name in GD.)

If I open those same links in Firefox, it prompts me to open/download the file *with the same name that appears in GD.* So clearly, there is some way to get the name of the file. **How can I get that name using command-line tools?**

(I'd like to avoid using something like a Python library for portability and ease of use, since this is going in a script that will likely sit around for a few years and then get used by someone who's never seen it before. But, high-overhead answers are still very welcome.)

Comment: Will this be useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/goodls

Comment: Yes! The getFilename() function provided just the hint I needed: capturing the header of the server's response. For any future readers, here's a shell-y way of getting the file name:


        curl 'https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/<FILEID>/export?format=docx' -L -D dumpHeader.out -o test.down
        cat dumpHeader.out | grep -P -e '(?<=filename=").*(?=")'


It may end up being easier/stabler to just use Goodls though. :P

(I'm not sure what's going wrong with my formatting here...)

Comment: I'm glad that is useful for you.